# Applications of companion matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, applications, companion-matrices

I'm looking for interesting applications of companion matrices. I can also use the Frobenius Normal Form.

I already covered the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem and the application to linearly recursive sequences and high-order scalar linear differential equations.

Comment: Within linear algebra: a matrix is similar to the companion matrix of its characteristic polynomial iff characteristic polynomial=minimal polynomial.

Comment: @julien : thanks ! I've already covered this, it's a consequence of Froebenius Normal Form. I'm still looking if anyone has other ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companion matrices can also be used to find the roots of a polynomial equation: the eigenvalues of the Companion Matrix are the roots of the polynomial equation. It is a very robust way of finding the roots of an equation, but not the most efficient (computationally).

Answer (score 1):

Companion forms of matrices are widely used in control theory, for example, in the [observable canonical form](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Standard_Forms#Observable_Canonical_Form) as well as the [controllable canonical form](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Standard_Forms#Controllable_Canonical_Form).

For a little more context of these canonical forms, you might read a little on [state space representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_representation) in control theory and their [relationship to transfer functions](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html) in control theory.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try to read about control theory.

Answer (score 1):

Companion matrices can be used to give matricial representations of some fields:

Let $k$ be a field and $k(\alpha)$ be a simple algebraic extension. If $A$ is the companion matrix of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then $k(\alpha) \simeq k(A)$.

For example, $\mathbb{C} \simeq \left\{ \left( \begin{matrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{matrix} \right) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$.